# Windows Phone make Segoe UI symbol not appear as emoticon

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, emoticons

I want to use the airplane Segoe UI Symbol in my C#/XAML Windows Phone 8 application.

I am inserting the symbol into my page like this:

```
<TextBlock>&#x2708;</TextBlock>
```

The symbol appears correctly in the "preview" pane in Visual Studio:

[image: Segoe UI airplane symbol correct]

However, when I run the application in the simulator or on the phone, it appears like this:

[image: Segoe UI airplane symbol incorrect]

This symbol looks the same as the one found in the emoticon keyboard:

[image: Airplane symbol on keyboard]

**How can I use the Segoe UI airplane symbol so that it appears totally white and not green as it appears in the emoticon keyboard?**

Comment: Yea it is strange.Am also getting like that even Foreground color of Textblock changes

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting the `FontFamily` on your `TextBlock` to Segoia UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent this behaviour by setting the [`DisplayColorEmoji`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.textoptions.displaycoloremoji%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) value to False (default is True):

```
<TextBlock TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji="False">&#x2708;</TextBlock>
```

This will stop the conversion you're seeing.